# Create a static IP for a single (Linux/Ubuntu) machine on an internal/home LAN?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ssh

At home I have a few old PC's (PC-1, PC-2) that automatically gets assigned a (dynamic?) IP and can connect to the internet via my wireless router.

I would like to assign a static IP to PC-1 so I can ssh to it from PC-2 and always use the same IP. I will only need to be able to do this from home so I don't need an external static IP (which I believe I also need to pay for at my ISP).

PC-1 and my other devices (iphones etc.) still need to have internet access as usual.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Internal IPv4 addresses are assigned by the DHCP server running on your home router. Search its settings for a feature called "static leases", "DHCP reservations", "reserved addresses", or something similar. There should be a table where you can configure the MAC address of PC-1 to always get assigned a specific IPv4 address.

(The name of this feature varies a lot, but in any case it should be near DHCP settings. However, in case you find the "static ARP" table, that is *not* what you're looking for – even though it looks very similar to static DHCP lease table.)

Alternatively, configure the DHCP lease lifetime to be a bit longer for the entire LAN, e.g. instead of 1 hour make it 24 or 48 hours. The router should remember even dynamic assignments for that duration, so with a 24-hour expiry, if PC-1 gets powered off in the evening, then powered on again in the morning, it should be able to reclaim its previous still-valid lease even if it's not a "static" one.

If neither is possible, configure an IP address *manually* on PC-1 itself (disabling DHCP and manually entering the netmask, gateway, DNS server settings). Internet access will continue to work as long as the same settings are entered.

(Pay attention to the "DHCP address range" setting in your router – manual configuration should use addresses *outside* of this range (but still inside the IP subnet overall). For example, if the network is 192.168.1.0/24 (255.255.255.0), and the DHCP range is ".100–.200", then using something like .50 or .99 for a non-DHCP machine is okay.)

---

Side note: Some home routers have IPv6 always enabled and advertise a "local" IPv6 prefix to the LAN, regardless of the ISP providing IPv6 connectivity or not. If your devices show an IPv6 address beginning with `fd` (*not* 'fe', *not* labelled "link-local") then you can just use that address for internal SSH-ing. This address is supposed to be static for as long as the router is the same.

---

Finally, consider using *host names* instead of addresses. Your router might provide internal DNS for host names that each PC advertises, e.g. `pc-1.lan` or `pc-1.home` (note that they must use DHCP to announce their hostname – PCs with manual IP configuration won't show up). Alternatively, Windows/Linux/macOS can support LLMNR and mDNS, both of which allow hosts to directly broadcast name queries across the entire LAN.

Comment: What “same settings” are you referring to if I go with creating a static ip manually on PC-1?

Comment: The same netmask (subnet mask), the same gateway, and (usually, though not necessarily) the same DNS servers.